# Retrieving the correct length and width for indesign exported .png

Tags: javascript, png, export, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am trying write a javascript application to output the length and width of a selected image/group in indesign (CS5) and save the selection to a .png file. The problem is that the length and width that I am generating using the visibleBounds of the selection are slightly different from the length and width of the exported image. More specifically, if the image height is greater than the width, the generated height will be the same as the resulting .png's height, but the generated width will be slightly smaller. Inversely, if the width is greater, the generated height will be slightly smaller. Here is the code I've been working with:

```
dest = Folder.selectDialog('Save report');
selected = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
filer = new File (dest+'/'+'testImage.png');
h = selected.visibleBounds[2] - selected.visibleBounds[0];
w = selected.visibleBounds[3] - selected.visibleBounds[1];
alert('height: '+h+'\nwidth: '+w);
selected.exportFile(ExportFormat.PNG_FORMAT, filer, false);
```

I should also point out, that this problem only occurs with relatively small images. It seems that the smaller the image, the more it is effected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have tried using geometricBounds instead of visibleBounds?

Comment: Yeah, geometricBounds gives me the exact same results :/

Comment: hm. Maybe try to set the units that your script uses. http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pc_ViewPreference.html  

    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.properties =  {
        horizontalMeasurementUnits : MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS,
        verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS
    }

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem also, even the exactly same image is exported on different sizes depending on its position on the page. I guess the problem is that inDesign is using centimeters or inches at the lowest level, instead of pixels.

However, what I finally did to solve this is to place the image on the inDesign document once it has been exported, and check the width and height to be sure of both values. **This solution is only valid to know what the image size is afterwards, once it has been exported**, I didn't find a way to know what the size will be before exporting it, as sometimes the size changes without any apparent reason:

```
selected.exportFile(ExportFormat.PNG_FORMAT, filer, false);
//These lines load the image into the document, check the size of the image file previously exported, and writes the correct measure into the XML file
var imageFile = File(filer);
var imageGraphic = app.activeDocument.pages.item(0).place(imageFile, null);
imageGraphicItem = imageGraphic[0];
var imageFrame = imageGraphicItem.parent;
var correctImageWidth = Math.round(imageFrame.visibleBounds[3]-imageFrame.visibleBounds[1]);
var correctImageHeight = Math.round(imageFrame.visibleBounds[2]-imageFrame.visibleBounds[0]);
//Do something
imageGraphicItem.parent.remove();
```

Hope it helps!